# Angular2 - can't deploy in a production environment

Tags: angular

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner of web development/Angular2 (and I have searched all over the internet)

I have created an Angular2 project using angular-cli.
I just don't get why I am not able to make it run in production.

Let's pretend I have the simplest app ever, these are the steps:

- **ng new name_of_my_app**
- **ng serve**

(Everything runs perfectly, locally, on port 4200; "app works!" is displayed by default)

- **ng build**

(Creates a dist folder containing the following files:

```
- favicon.ico
- index.html
- inline.bundle.js
- inline.bundle.map
- main.bundle.js
- main.bundle.map
- styles.bundle.js
- styles.bundle.map
```

At this point, as many have suggested, I've simply copied the content of the dist folder on my web server, but nothing happens: index.html just displays "Loading...".

Locally, opening index.html with any browser, the result is the same: "Loading..." is displayed.

Comment: Open browser developer tools and see what's the error in the console and paste it in the question.

Comment: Nothing is displayed by the browser's console.

Comment: You have to run it on some server like apache or nginx.

Comment: Is the .js bundle included in the index.html as a script tag?

Comment: @AmitDahan: it is <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>

Comment: What are you using for your packages? If you are using `npm` most dev. environments will not publish the `node_modules` folder with the content, it is up to you to execute `npm i --production` (*or whatever*) to pull the packages into the deployed folder.

Comment: I think @IgorJanković is on point here.  You can't "open index.html locally", Angular is an ajax framework, and **requires** a server in order to load your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.html` probably says something like ..

```
<component>
  loading .. 
</component>
```

Here the text loading is displayed until the component is loaded. It sounds like it cant load the component. A path issue probably? Have you set the base path correct in production?

For example ..

Here all requests will be prefixed with this path which may or may not be what you want.

Check you browers's NET tab to see if any requests are failing (with 404 not found). If so, fix up the paths for the failing requests.